# 802.1x NPS Machine authentication

Tags: radius, nps, eap, aruba, 802.1x

We are trying to implement **802.1x** to authenticate wirelless users (Aruba Controller) through RADIUS (**Windows server 2019 NPS**),

For mobile phones and guests devices, we have ***successfully*** configured the authentication via user (**AD Account**) , but for the LAN devices (**Windows 10 Domaine joined computers**) we are trying the set **machine authentication** but unfortunatly it seems to be impossible , I have noticed that in **NPS event log**, the computer name is passed as a user account and not a computer account:

---

`The Network Policy Server denied access to a user.`

`Contact the NPS server administrator for more information.`

`1- User:`

`- Security ID: **NULL SID**`

`- Account name: **host/machinename.domain.com**`

`- Account domain: **domain.com**`

`- Full account name: **domain.com\machinename$**`

`2- Computer:`

`- Security ID: ****NULL SID****`

`- Account Name : **-**`

`- Full account name: **-**`

`- Identifier of the called station: **10:LAN-SSID**`

`- Calling station identifier: **FF0000000000**`

---

down here is our configuration of the NPS Network policy and the wireless profile on a windows 10 domain joined computer :

1- NPS Network policy-**Conditions**:

`- Computers groups : Domain\Domain Computers`

`- NAS port type : wireless-other or wirelless-IEEE 802.11`

2- NPS Network policy : **Contraints**

`- EAP protocols types : Microsoft: PEAP (Protected EAP)`

`- EAP Types: Secured password (EAP-MSCHAP version 2)`

3- NPS Network policy : **Settings**

`- Framed-Protocol : PPP` `- Service-Type : Framed` `- Tunnel-Type : Virtual LANs (VLAN)` `Tunnel-Medium-Type 802 (Includes all 802 media plus Ethernet canonical ...` `- Tunnel-Pvt-Group-ID: Our VLAN ID` `- Termination-Action : RADIUS-Request`

**Windows 10 WLAN Card configuration :**

1- Windows 10 wireless profile : **EAP-PEAP**

6- Windows 10 wireless profile: **EAP-MSCHAPv2**

7- Windows 10 wireless profile: **do not use username and domain**

8- Windows 10 wireless profile: **Authentication mode : computer**

**Sorry for the long post.**

Best regards